# BroadcastReceiver doesn't react on external intents

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver

I'm trying to implement Tasker support in my app. I've declared intent-filter in the Manifest file and wrote the Receiver, but it doesn't work (nothing is logged, my app does not react on these intents).

I've tested it sending intents from tasker like this:

`ACTION: START_SERVICE`

`package: com.example.appname`

Manifest declaration:

```
<receiver android:name="ExIntentReceiver">  
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="com.example.appname.START_SERVICE" />
    <action android:name="com.example.appname.STOP_SERVICE" />
  </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Receiver:

```
Public class ExtIntentReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {


 @Override
   public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
      String action = intent.getAction();
  if(action.equals("com.example.appname.START_SERVICE"))    {
        Log.v("service", "is started");
      } else if(action.equals("com.example.appname.STOP_SERVICE"))  {
          Log.v("service", "is stopped");
      }

   }

}
```

Comment: you are sending the broadcast message from other application?

Comment: Yes, from the Tasker.

Comment: Does the ExtIntentReceiver react on internal intents?

Comment: Yes, it does react on internal ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually I see one place that might be a reason. When you sending intent you specify the package name `com.example.appname`, but what is specified in the AndroidManifest.xml? If you use package name in the intent then this name must match the package name form AndroidManifest.xml of receiving app.

Comment: Package name declared in the AndroidManifest.xml is also com.example.appname

Comment: @soulreaver Provide code snippet where you creating Intent and sending Broadcast. Are you sending some extras? Also I am confused about `ACTION: START_SERVICE` are you actually sending action as "START_SERVICE"? Cause you need to use full action name as "com.example.appname.START_SERVICE".